# Vim motion vertical version of f & t?

Tags: vim, motion

In vim, I really love `f` & `t` in Normal mode. Are there vertical versions of these? If not, what's the best way to jump so many lines downward to a word that I see? Do I just have to count the lines and do `12j` or something?

Comment: In addition to my answer below, you might also try out the relative number option (`:set relativenumber`), which makes it easy to count how many rows up or down you want to move. It's not for everyone, but I find it useful sometimes. I have it set to toggle between number and relative number when I hit `<leader>n`

Comment: I also find `relativenumber` helpful for this. For toggling it, I use [Jeff Kreeftmeijer’s numbertoggle plugin](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle) — it turns `relativenumber` off in insert mode and enables it in normal mode.

Answer (score 7):

Can you use `/foo` (or `?foo` for backwards)? I tend to use that more than `t` or `f` anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I think you'll love the [EasyMotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) plugin.

You'll type `<leader>fb` to go to a `b`, horizontally **and** vertically.

*(you can also find the vim.org mirror git [here](https://github.com/vim-scripts/EasyMotion#readme))*

Comment: The author has his own [repository](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) for EasyMotion. I think it's better source than the vim-scripts mirror, in my opinion.

Comment: @evaryont I agree, I edited my answer. I use the vim-scripts mirror because it's a central place for me (and for Vundle :)  http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak), a plugin I wrote for this very reason. It enables you to jump to any location in three keystrokes by specifying the first two characters of the target:

```
s{char}{char}
```

For example, `sab` moves the cursor to the next instance of the string "ab". And `Sab` moves *backwards* to the previous instance of "ab".

It also supports:

- visual mode
- operations (like `dzab`, `czab`, and `yzab`)
- operation-repeat with `.`
- motion-repeat with `;` and `,`

vim-sneak is similar to [vim-seek](https://github.com/goldfeld/vim-seek), with many improvements.